# How to count matching words from 2 csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files, dictionary.csv and story.csv. I wanted to count how many words in story.csv per row matches with words from dictionary.csv

Below are truncated examples

```
Story.csv 
id    STORY
0     Jennie have 2 shoes, a red heels and a blue sneakers
1     The skies are pretty today
2     One of aesthetic color is grey
```

```
Dictionary.csv
red
green
grey
blue
black
```

The output i expected is

```
output.csv
id    STORY                                                  Found
0     Jennie have 2 shoes, a red heels and a blue sneakers    2
1     The skies are pretty today                              0
2     One of aesthetic color is grey                          1
```

These are the codes i have so far, but i only got NaN(empty cells)

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv

news=pd.read_csv("Story.csv") 
dictionary=pd.read_csv("Dictionary.csv")


news['STORY'].value_counts()

news['How many found in 1'] = dictionary['Lists'].map(news['STORY'].value_counts())

news.to_csv("output.csv")
```

I tried using .str.count as well, but i kept on getting zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

#create the sample data frame
data = {'id':[0,1,2],'STORY':['Jennie have 2 shoes, a red heels and a blue sneakers',\
'The skies are pretty today',\
'One of aesthetic color is grey']}

word_list = ['red', 'green', 'grey', 'blue', 'black']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#start counting
df['Found'] = df['STORY'].astype(str).apply(lambda t: pd.Series({word: t.count(word) for word in word_list}).sum())
#alternatively, can use this
#df['Found'] = df['STORY'].astype(str).apply(lambda t: sum([t.count(word) for word in word_list]))
```

Output

```
df
#   id  STORY                                                Found
#0  0   Jennie have 2 shoes, a red heels and a blue sneakers 2
#1  1   The skies are pretty today                           0
#2  2   One of aesthetic color is grey                       1
```

Bonus edit: if you want to see the detailed break down of word count by word, then run this

```
df['STORY'].astype(str).apply(lambda t: pd.Series({word: t.count(word) for word in word_list}))

#   red     green   grey    blue    black
#0  1       0       0       1       0
#1  0       0       0       0       0
#2  0       0       1       0       0
```